# We have a community run tumblr; here's how you can contribute

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, blog

[Literature now has a community run tumblr](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/). It's titled "One Minute Reviews", and its purpose, as the title implies, is to post quick reviews of literature.

Tumblr was chosen to host the blog because it has a large community of people interested in literature.

Answer (score 7):

## How can I get involved

The easiest way is to write a review. They're quick and fun to write -- [you can take a look at the reviews that have already been published](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/) to get an idea of what we're looking for.

To post the review, please ping me (Hamlet) in our site's chat room with a copy of the review. Or, tumblr has a feature (that I just enabled) that [allows people to submit posts for approval that I can then approve](https://oneminutereviews.tumblr.com/submit). So you can do that as well (but ping me about it on chat so I remember to look).

If you want to get involved in the design of the blog and/or if you want to use the blog to engage with people on tumblr, ping me and I'll add you as a user on tumblr. I would prefer not to add people as admins for the tumblr blog unless I know you well, simply because once you make someone an admin on tumblr you can't remove them.

Comment: Are you currently the only person able to post reviews single-handedly? Might be nice to add at least all the site mods, so that we can post new reviews even when you aren't around.

Comment: @Randal'Thor yeah; I just created it. If you create a tumblr account, I would be happy to add you.

Comment: Is there an option to "add" someone else to have control of the blog?

Comment: @Gallifreyan you can add people as regular users, who I believe can just post without approval, or you can add people as admins, which is irreversible but who can do things like edit the theme.

Comment: Really? I didn't find that. Which settings window is it under (link)?